# Is it possible to have a charging unit and output unit connected to a battery at the same time?

Tags: batteries, dc, lithium-ion

I am very new to DIY and electronics stuff, so please excuse myself having little knowledge about this stuff.

Here is what I am trying to do:
[image]

Assuming I have both things (The Converter with USB output and the mini-USB input charger) connected to the battery, and only one thing on at a time, would it short circuit either of the modules, or the battery? Also, can I even have the charger and discharger connected together and to the battery without causing a short circuit?

Comment: related (possibly duplicate): http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170857/how-can-the-sparkfun-lipo-usb-charger-power-other-devices-at-the-same-time-as-ch

Answer (score 2):

It is very common to have a charging source and a load connected to a battery at the same time, so that it looks like you are charging and discharging the battery simultaneously.

What actually happens is that, if the charger can supply more current than the load demands, most current will go directly from charger to load, with any excess current going to charge the battery.

If the load demands more current than the charger can supply, the battery will supply the additional currrent the load requires.  If this condition persists, the battery will become discharged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It would work but I would approach with caution. I charge my phone all the time while I'm using it.

Comment: so, if I connect the positives of all three things, and I connect the negatives of all three things, it would not cause a short circuit?

Comment: You'll have to draw a circuit then.

Comment: Just checked your link. Should be okay. IF current demand on your boost circuit is high, your battery might not charge.