# is it OK to use battery while charging?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am using the tp4056 module with protection to charge NCR18650 li-ion battery.
is it OK to connect to the load to the battery while it is charging?

I am using a booster to boost 3.7V to 9V(load voltage 9V) and load current is around 100mA

Comment: We can't possibly know what load.

Comment: I am using a booster to boost 3.7V to 9V(load voltage 9V) and load current is around 100mA

Comment: more related and duplictae questions: [Can I charge and discharge a NiCd/NiMh battery at the same time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/52973/7036), [How can the Lithium-polymer USB charger power other devices at the same time as charging?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/170857/7036)